# How To automate Email Attachments from outlook to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-functions

We receive couple of reports from service Now to outlook as an Excel format.
Same attachments which is excel format I would like to convert to CSV UTF-8 load into azure blob storage daily.

How can I automate this process.

Comment: What part of this process is related to Snowflake?

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box I would recommend Logic Apps. It has a connector for Outlook and Storage accounts.

Trigger "When a new email arrives" and then the tasks:

1. "Get Attachment V2"
2. "Create blob V2"

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the insights. I would like to bring up result.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the insights. I would like to bring up result.  I have tried Trigger "When a new email arrives" and then the tasks:

"Get Attachment V2"
"Create blob V2" .    Without Get attachment i am able to get the files to blob but CSV format is coming as JSOn/Text file. and with attachment, files are not getting processed to blob. Please help